# Can't see reason why my kafka server suddenly stopped in a period of time

Tags: java, xml, configuration, apache-kafka

I cant figure out why my kafka broker suddenly stopped / killed after 2 or 3 active days.

My kafka log dont specific another error detail, it was simply `Killed` and couldn't find any logs in my kafka server that describe more useful information about this error.

I am new on kafka. So some kafka configs maybe i misunderstood them

Here is my kafka config server:

```
advertised.host.name = null
advertised.listeners = null
advertised.port = null
alter.config.policy.class.name = null
alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.num = 11
alter.log.dirs.replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
authorizer.class.name = 
auto.create.topics.enable = true
auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
background.threads = 10
broker.id = 0
broker.id.generation.enable = true
broker.rack = null
client.quota.callback.class = null
compression.type = producer
connection.failed.authentication.delay.ms = 100
connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
controlled.shutdown.enable = true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
create.topic.policy.class.name = null
default.replication.factor = 1
delegation.token.expiry.check.interval.ms = 3600000
delegation.token.expiry.time.ms = 86400000
delegation.token.master.key = null
delegation.token.max.lifetime.ms = 604800000
delete.records.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1
delete.topic.enable = true
fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms = 0
group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
host.name = 
inter.broker.listener.name = null
inter.broker.protocol.version = 2.1-IV2
kafka.metrics.polling.interval.secs = 10
kafka.metrics.reporters = []
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
listener.security.protocol.map = PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
listeners = null
log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
log.cleaner.enable = true
log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
log.cleaner.threads = 1
log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
log.dirs = /tmp/kafka-logs
log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
log.flush.interval.ms = null
log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
log.flush.start.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
log.message.downconversion.enable = true
log.message.format.version = 2.1-IV2
log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
log.preallocate = false
log.retention.bytes = -1
log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
log.retention.hours = 168
log.retention.minutes = null
log.retention.ms = null
log.roll.hours = 168
log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
log.roll.jitter.ms = null
log.roll.ms = null
log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
max.connections.per.ip.overrides = 
max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots = 1000
message.max.bytes = 1000012
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
min.insync.replicas = 1
num.io.threads = 8
num.network.threads = 3
num.partitions = 1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
num.replica.alter.log.dirs.threads = null
num.replica.fetchers = 1
offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
offsets.retention.minutes = 10080
offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
offsets.topic.replication.factor = 1
offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
password.encoder.cipher.algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
password.encoder.iterations = 4096
password.encoder.key.length = 128
password.encoder.keyfactory.algorithm = null
password.encoder.old.secret = null
password.encoder.secret = null
port = 9092
principal.builder.class = null
producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
queued.max.request.bytes = -1
queued.max.requests = 500
quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
quota.window.num = 11
quota.window.size.seconds = 1
replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
replication.quota.window.num = 11
replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
request.timeout.ms = 30000
reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
sasl.server.callback.handler.class = null
security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
ssl.cipher.suites = []
ssl.client.auth = none
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
transaction.abort.timed.out.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 60000
transaction.max.timeout.ms = 900000
transaction.remove.expired.transaction.cleanup.interval.ms = 3600000
transaction.state.log.load.buffer.size = 5242880
transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 1
transaction.state.log.segment.bytes = 104857600
transactional.id.expiration.ms = 604800000
unclean.leader.election.enable = false
zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
zookeeper.max.in.flight.requests = 10
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
zookeeper.set.acl = false
zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
```

Sorry for your late response. Here is my zookeeper log

```
`[2019-07-12 11:45:50,196] INFO Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:48000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
```

[2019-07-12 11:45:50,215] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:48000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,239] INFO Established session 0x10199caa9400000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /127.0.0.1:48000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,360] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x1 zxid:0x200 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/consumers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /consumers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,387] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x201 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/ids Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,391] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x3 zxid:0x202 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/topics (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,394] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x4 zxid:0x203 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/changes Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/changes (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,397] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x5 zxid:0x204 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/admin/delete_topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /admin/delete_topics (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,399] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x6 zxid:0x205 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/brokers/seqid Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/seqid (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,402] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x7 zxid:0x206 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/isr_change_notification Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /isr_change_notification (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,405] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x8 zxid:0x207 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/latest_producer_id_block Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /latest_producer_id_block (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,407] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0x9 zxid:0x208 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/log_dir_event_notification Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /log_dir_event_notification (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,409] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0xa zxid:0x209 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/topics Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/topics (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,411] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0xb zxid:0x20a txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/clients Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/clients (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,413] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0xc zxid:0x20b txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/users Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/users (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:50,414] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:create cxid:0xd zxid:0x20c txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/brokers Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /config/brokers (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:52,943] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:multi cxid:0x32 zxid:0x210 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/reassign_partitions Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/reassign_partitions (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2019-07-12 11:45:52,996] INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x10199caa9400000 type:multi cxid:0x34 zxid:0x211 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a aborting remaining multi ops. Error Path:/admin/preferred_replica_election Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /admin/preferred_replica_election (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)`

Comment: Did you run it on Windows? Maybe with cmd or Powershell?

Comment: No, i run it on linux centos 6

Comment: Can you post whatever logs you have from the application talking to Kafka?  Or from the zookeeper servers?